# Confusion on Cauchy's first theorem on limits

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a doubt on applying Cauchy's 1st theorem on limits. Kindly enlighten me....

> Example 1: $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {1}{n} (1+\frac {1}{2}+....\frac{1}{n})$.

Here I am taking $a_n = 1/n \to 0 $ as $n \to \infty$. So $ \frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n} \to 0\implies$ given example 1 limit converges to 0

Now take example 2:

> Example 2: $ \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {1}{n} (\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac {1}{n+2}+....\frac{1}{n+n})$

Here in textbook I have seen

$a_n = 1/(n+n) \to 0$ and so $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {1}{n} (\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac {1}{n+2}+....\frac{1}{n+n}) \to 0$ ------>(1)

If $a_n = 1/(n+n) = 1/(2n)$

can we take in this way?
$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {1}{n} (\frac{1}{2}+\frac {1}{2*2}+....\frac{1}{2*n})$ ------>(2)

Is (2) wrong? If so, can you pls elaborate?

Comment: Can you tell us which textbooks are you using? For now the argument seem very sloppy (though $(1)$ is correct).

Comment: (2) i have written.  (1) is present in any text book or google. I am confused with 2 n's which only 1 n will be substituted and other n is kept as it is

Comment: I am saying that if you are using Cauchy's first theorem with $a_n = \frac{1}{n+n}$, then you should end up in (2) instead of (1). If a textbook claims that (1) is true by Cauchy's first theorem, then the argument is very sloppy.

Comment: Sir pls see example (2) in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930373/limits-and-cauchys-first-theorem

Comment: The argument by the questioner there is incorrect.....

Comment: Sir i have seen examples(like example (2) in the link) under cauchy 1st theorem on limits where there will be two n's. 1 n will be kept as fixed as other n is moved from 1 to n. Pls kindly elaborate if possible

Comment: @Magento Have you got the answer to this problem ? I have encountered this myself in numerous occasions in textbooks and can't understand the reason. If you are through with this problem, request you to kindly explain this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not apply the theorem for the limit given in example 2 (because each element in the sequence $\left\{\frac{1}{1+n},\ldots,\frac{1}{n+n} \right\}$ is dependent on $n$). But you can calculate the limit as follows

$$ 0 \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n \, \left( \frac{1}{1+n} + \ldots+ \frac{1}{n+n} \right) \le \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n \, \left( \frac{n}{n+1} \right) \to 0 $$
Thus, by the squeeze theorem $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1n \, \left( \frac{1}{1+n} + \ldots+ \frac{1}{n+n} \right)=0$.